# Can I see errors in angelic covers with wits+composure?

Tags: demon-the-descent, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I think I've read somewhere that you can use wits+composure to see small errors...tells in angelic covers but didn't find the passage.

Am I right that that is somewhere? Or was it a wrong memory?

Comment: @Ahriman yepp although I'm pretty sure I read an explicite rule somehwere in a gray box about the errors (or maybe a comment in a gray box with the mentioned roll and telling that errors are seen then). my problem is mostly not sure which book and where there

Comment: Aka something that was NOT demonspecific but instead something everyone can roll (thus not aetheric resonance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's a wrong memory.

I have checked the core rulebook of Demon the Descent, the Flowers of Hell book and Heirs to Hell and found nothing that matches what you describe.

There are some possible confusing matches:

- Trained Observer (Demon the Descent core rules p291)
- Hallucination Numina (Demon the Descent core rules p350)
- Mortal Mask Numina (Demon the Descent core rules p351)
- Quantum Understanding (Heirs to Hell p33)
- Unseen Sense (Heirs to Hell p33-34)

All in all, the Wits + Composure roll is generally used as the "Perception" check, so you could rig something together based on the Cover rules for demons (since we know that the God-Machine provides its Angels with matching covers).

Comment: I think the original question was almost definitely referring to the Mortal Mask Numen, which angels have when they have human forms. It wasn't until Demon came out that the same effect was given the synonymous and more detailed 'Cover' system when it's from the perspective of the Unchained. As written, angels under their Mortal Mask do have flaws that can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

You probably read the **Mortal Mask** Numen from The God-Machine Chronicle (and Appendix II in Demon). Angels with human forms like The Lady in Red have it, angels without human forms like The Candle Maker lack it.

The Demon books refer to an angel's human guise as Cover instead, but in core books that mechanic doesn't exist, so Mortal Mask is effectively a synonym. Going by RAW, it does seem to oddly imply that the Fall improved their disguise and removed the subtle flaws that mortals can detect, since demonic Cover doesn't give this same opportunity. (High ranking angels could have pretty enormous Finesse, though.)

> Mortal Mask
>   This Numen disguises a Materialized entity as a human
>   and can be used at the same time as the Materialize Mani-
>   festation Effect. Using the Numen costs 1 Essence and the
>   human seeming lasts for activation successes in hours. The
>   human “costume” is flawed — witnesses may make a Wits +
>   Composure roll penalized by the entity’s Finesse to realize
>   that something is wrong. Characters able to sense the entity
>   in Twilight do not suffer a penalty to the roll.

Comment: I think that there's a difference from a GM generate angelic cover, created and maintained by the GM, and an angelic mortal mask.  The latter occurs when an angel chooses to Manifest, rather than when it is on assignment from the GM.  I base this on the crunch of angel-jacking which describes the materialization of angels in a fashion very different from a Manifestation.